# Increment alphabetical string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to increment an alphabetical string in Ruby.

The string format is

> A clients unique ID. This is six characters long and must be in the
>   form [A-Z][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]. The numbers [0-9]
>   at the beginning of an ID are legal characters, but reserved for
>   future use.

The next string after AAAAAA is AAAAAB. Once AAAAAZ is reached the next string is AAAABA and so on.

What is the simplest method to generate these strings in Ruby?

I will be storing the last user ID in a variable for example `lastUID = AAAAAA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
"AAAAAA".succ
# => "AAAAAB"
"AAAAAZ".succ
# => "AAAABA"
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed `.succ` but thanks! I'll accept the answer once it allows me to. Is there any way to programmatically create the initial `AAAAAA` rather than have to have like `lastUID = 'AAAAAA'` (ugly)?

Comment: `lastUID = "A" * 6` and `lastUID.next`

Comment: Yeah, you can create strings of arbitrary length with `"X" * n` where `n` is how many you want.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
lastUID = "A" * 6

100.times do |i|
  lastUID = lastUID.next
end
```